# How to deal with picklist in MS CRM 2011 if it's not a global

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to deal with picklist in MS CRM 2011, however it doesn't work properly. Actually, I've got 5 parameters in picklist, but I got only 2 by this code.

```js
function InstOwnerPickListOnLoadStage()
{
   lSub = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_status");
   lSub.originalPicklistValues = lSub.getAttribute().getOptions();

   lKAZNACHOptionList = new Array();
   lRISKIPolOptionList = new Array();

   lKAZNACHOptionList .push(0,1);
   lRISKIPolOptionList .push(2,3);

   document.FillPicklist = function (iDesiredOptions)
   {
       for (var i=0; i< lSub.originalPicklistValues.length; i++) 
       {
           for (var j=0; j< iDesiredOptions.length; j++) 
           {
               if(iDesiredOptions[j] == i)
               {
                  lSub.addOption( lSub.originalPicklistValues[i]);
                  break;
               }
           }  
       }
   }   

   var optionset = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_status"); 
   optionset.clearOptions(); 

   document.FillPicklist(lKAZNACHOptionList );

   //InstOwnerPickListOnChangeStage(null); 
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what is happening here? What do you mean by 'deal with picklist' - trying to add extra options?

Comment: @glosrob 3  yes, exactly. You know, I've not had experience work in pick list before. And I couldn't understand what this code for ;) In GUI it's just changes order parametrs in pick list. Mind you, some of them just dissapear ;((

Comment: So why use it? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you'd be better off stating the problem you are trying to solve in your question.

Comment: @glosrob I wonder do we need put some code for picklist in order to initialize it (I mean something function controlling values of picklist)? or it's enough just created a set of parameters for my picklist

Comment: You don't need anything, you create your field of type OptionSet add some options you can make one as default. Add your field to the form picklist and it's ready to work.

Comment: @Pedro Azevedo That's code was used by previous my colleage but I'm not sure need I used it coz it doesn't work correctly =) The comment to this peace of code is: Control function values of​​picklist field status
/ / Initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns only two items because you are saying that you need only 2 that is the length of array `lKAZNACHOptionList` and you only need the index 0 and 1. For get more items you have manipulate the array `lKAZNACHOptionList` and insert more items.

Comment: oh, Almost correct, but when a choose a value of the field it won't show this value =(

Comment: if this is the solution, please mark it as the accepted answer.  If it is not the answer, please feel free to answer your own question and mark it as the answer (even though it will not award you points, it will help people to know you don't need more help on this question.)